# Can we add IF condition inside dynamic URL on detail page button

Tags: apex, custom-button, urlhacking

I have to implement dynamic URL with IF condition.I have tried below but it is not working

```
/a02/e?retURL=%2F{! Case.Id }&RecordType=012D00000006iRF&ent=01I200000002ywE
&CF00N20000002M9yd={!Case.CaseNumber}
&Name={!Case.CaseNumber}
&00ND00000040e6D={!Case.Incident_Type__c}
&00N20000002MAUe="Open"
&00Nd00000074kmE={!Account.MP1_Customer_ID__c} 
&00Nd0000007dYNu={!IF(Ispickval(Opportunity.Business_Group__c,'Ultrasound'),'','!Account.GTM_Region__c')}
```

Even tried like below also but didnt workout.

```
00Nd0000007dYNu={IF((TEXT(Opportunity.Business_Group__c)=='Ultrasound'),'',(TEXT(!Account.GTM_Region__c)))}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing correct but 2 different mistakes  in both try

try with below code

```
&00Nd0000007dYNu={!IF(Ispickval(Opportunity.Business_Group__c,'Ultrasound'),'',Text(Account.GTM_Region__c))}
```

Comment: @ratan-Getting below error:
Error: Field Account.GTM_Region__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

Comment: @Jackvardy use `Text(Account.GTM_Region__c)`

Comment: @ratan-Its not evaluating if condition.I can see field is still blank.

Comment: @Jackvardy check in url if the value getting passed or not? I guess 00Nd0000007dYNu this id may be not correct

Comment: @ratan-That id belongs to the field i wanted to update. I think IF condition does not work in case of URL.